# Is Weblog Expert reliable?

Tags: statistics

My boss asked me if Weblog expert (http://www.weblogexpert.com/lite.htm) is reliable in calculating the average time of the incoming visitors in a web site. Since HTTP is a stateless protocol, I think that the average time might be something left to personal interpretation. Does any one uses Weblog Expert? Is the visitor's average time reliable? Does anyone understand its criteria about how it process Apache logs to understand the average time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the WebLog Expert Lite help, the following definition:

> Visitor - The program determines number of visitors by the IP addresses. If a request from an IP address came after 30 minutes since the last request from this IP, it is considered to belong to a different visitor. Requests from spiders aren't used to determine visitors.

That's a fairly useful heuristic to determine a visitor's visit, if all you have to go on is a timestamp and a requesting IP address.  (I'm not sure how Web Log Expert determines a visitor is a spider, but it was irrelevant to my purpose.)

However, on closer inspection, I found the visitor average time to be very variable for our web app; some users request only a page or two, others are on for hours.  So a single metric of "Average visit duration" might not give you a perfect understanding of your site's traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on that site in particular, but average time is usually calculated using some very clever bits of javascript.

You can set events on various parts of the page in javascript which fire off requests to servers. For example, when the user navigates away from a page or clicks on a link or closes the window the browser can send off a javascript request to their servers letting them know that the user has left. While this isn't 100% reliable, I think it provides a reasonable estimate for how long people spend there.

Answer (score 0):

I get entirely different results if I change "Visitor session timeout".
Our internal network people (the majority of our visitors) all go to our website (external host) from the same IP (through our ISP), so the only way to determine a new visitor is by this Timeout.  Choosing 1, 5 or 10 minutes creates very different results.  HIGHLY UNRELIABLE.  The only thing to do is be consistent and use the same parameters for comparative results, i.e., increased/decreased traffic.  By the way, the update to WebLog Expert (version 7 -> 8) through that all out the window with entirely different counting mechanisms.